# Use Template Strings (ES6) as a returned variable in a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to use a Template String from a variable in function.

**This is a working example (not a variable)**

```
let f = function () {
  return `Hello ${this.name}!`
}
f.bind({
  name: 'Stackoverflow-User'
})(); // Hello Stackoverflow-User!
```

**This is the not working example (in a variable)**

```
let s = `Hello ${this.name}!`;
let f = function () {
  return s;
}
f.bind({
  name: 'Stackoverflow-User'
})(); // Hello undefined!
```

Comment: Umm, why not just do `let f = s` in your final solution???

Comment: Oh no .. now I am confused ... I've worked in my solution with a fix value instead of a variable. I will update my solution ...

Comment: @FelixKling: That's a horrible duplicate imo

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I noticed that after I read it completely. Do you have a better one? Didn't you answer such a question?

Comment: @FelixKling: [the two I linked from there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused#comment48130107_30003353) are pretty canonical, but not sure whether they're a duplicate of this here.

Comment: @Bergi: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22607806/1048572 fits IMO. At least it's the same problem. Unfortunately this question doesn't really contain a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
let f = function () {
  return `Hello ${this.name}!`
}
```

gets compiled into this:

```
let f = function () {
  return "Hello " + this.name.toString() + "!";
}
```

and it will work as soon as `f` is called as a method of proper object.
Expression gets evaluated each time you call the function.

And in your second case:

```
var s = "Hello " + this.name.toString() + "!";

let f = function () {
  return s;
}
```

that `s` gets its value only once - at load time and with wrong `this`.

The only way to make it work that way is to generate function from it:

```
let s = new Function("return `Hello ${this.name}!`;");
```

and use it as:

```
let f = function () {
  return s.call(this);
}
```

A bit weird but will work.

Comment: Because "this" was manipulated I changed it a bit but inspired by your solution. See my update above! Thanks.

Comment: `return s.bind(this)();` is just a waste of memory and CPU. You create another function object. Just do `return s.call(this);` instead.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the `eval` solution.