# String interpolation on variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have a variable `str`

```
var str = "123"
```

Now I could do `` console.log(`Hello ${str}`) `` and it will print `Hello 123`

Now I have another variable `strnew`

```
var strnew = 'Hello ${str}'
```

Note (based on answers/comments) - `strnew` is read from a file, so its always a string and cant be replaced with `` ` ``

How do I `console.log(...)` to print `Hello 123`

Is it possible wihtout any kind of `eval()`

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40235363/476

Comment: I think the best way in this case is to use function, that accepts `str` and uses this template string inside.

Comment: I think this is just example, if you have very long string with multiple concatenations - template string is better.

Comment: If string is from file maybe it is better to use `_.template` instead, or some other template engine. I don't see any option to generate template string from string.

Comment: use regex replace like `strnew.replace(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g,()=>window[RegExp.$1])` if you are not using scopes

Comment: What is the reason of using string templates with simple strings?

Comment: Instead of using ES6 template strings try to use a template engine like Moustache and use the compile() function for getting the result

Comment: @TheReason not related reason.. angular2 doesnt have an equivalent angular1 $compile functionality

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With something as simple as `${str}` you can use a simple string replacement:

```js
var template = (tpl, args) => tpl.replace(/\${(\w+)}/g, (_, v) => args[v]);

var tpl = 'Hello ${str} and ${other}';

console.log(template(tpl, {str: 'foo', other: 'bar'}));
```

In a general case, no, not possible without eval (short of writing your own js interpreter), because `${...}` can contain arbitrary expressions.

For completeness' sake, here's the eval solution:

```js
var template = function(tpl, args) {
    var keys = Object.keys(args),
        fn = new Function(...keys, 
          'return `' + tpl.replace(/`/g, '\\`') + '`');
    return fn(...keys.map(x => args[x]));
};


function test() {
    var myTpl = 'Hello ${str + "!"} and ${other.toUpperCase()}';
    console.log(template(myTpl, {str: 'foo', other: 'bar'}));
}

test();
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I edited your post instead of suggesting an edit, but I reverted it. new Function('', 'return `' + tpl + '`'); could be optimized to new Function('return `' + tpl + '`');

Comment: Great answer!! This should be the accepted answer. Give me a day or two to confirm.

Comment: _`template(myTpl, str='foo', other='bar')`_ this code implicitly creates two global variables. Argumants passed to the function are never used.

Comment: @Qwertiy: right-o, too much python recently ;) fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function instead of just string.

```js
var strnew = function(str){
  return `Hello ${str}`;
}
var str = "123";
console.log(strnew(str))
```

Comment: IMHO the best solution and probably the way template literals were intended to be used.

Comment: Template strings are read from a file, they are not in the OP's code.

Comment: @georg yes, he added this note later, I wrote comment about this.

Comment: yes. based on answers, i had to adjust my question. thanks @dm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704827/882936), here is a bit of black magic code that achieves what you want. Disclaimer - this is for fun / very limited and exotic application. It is likely to be very slow and break down on lots of edge cases, but with a limited scope of your question it works.

```js
function getString(){
 return "calculating ${foo} + ${bar} = ${foo + bar}";
}

var localEnvironmentProxy = new Proxy({}, {
    has(target, prop) { return true; },
    get(target, prop) { return (prop in target ? target : window)[prop]; }
  });
  
  with(localEnvironmentProxy){
  
 var foo = 1;
 var bar = 2;
  
 var templString = getString();
 
 var fnFullText = 'with(arguments[0]){ return `' + templString + '`;}';
 
 var tempalteFn = new Function(fnFullText);
    
 console.log(tempalteFn(localEnvironmentProxy));
    //calculating 1 + 2 = 3
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I built off of [@georg's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118285/3443552) for a typescript solution:

```
public renderTemplate(templateStr: string, args: any): string {
  templateStr = templateStr.replace(/`/g, '\\`');
  
  const keys = Object.keys(args);

  const fn = new Function(...keys, 'return `' + templateStr + '`');

  return fn(...keys.map(key => args[key]));
}
```

The usage is virtually the same as well.