# ES6 String interpolation

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Can you perform replacements on a string put in a variable?  This won't work.

```
var obj = {a:1};
var a = '`${obj.a}`';

console.log(String.raw a);
```

Comment: Not without using `eval` (one way or the other).

Comment: Sounds a bit like a duplicate of [Defer execution for ES6 Template Literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22607806/1048572)

Comment: Be aware that so far not even Chrome fully implements `String.raw`. http://tddbin.com/#?kata=es6/language/template-strings/raw So what are you using to test it? Node.js?

Comment: Chrome.  Result should be '1'

Comment: @connexo These tests are completely wrong. `String.raw` is not supposed to behave like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what you mean. Is the expected output `1`?

If so, your string template literal is going to look like

```
var a = `${obj.a}`
```

instead of

```
var a = '`${obj.a}`'
```