# Nested String Interpolation or Delaying String Interpolation

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I am creating functions containing strings that need interpolation:

```
let createPFunc = (string) => {
    return () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(`${string}`);
                resolve();
            }, 2000);
        })
    }
}
let f1 = createPFunc('String 1: ${string}');
let f2 = createPFunc('String 2: `${string}`');

f1(`search 1`).then(() => f2('search 2'))
```

What it prints is:

```
String 1: ${string}
String 2: `${string}`
```

I want it to print:

```
String 1: search 1
String 2: search 2
```

I tried different quoting variations, but can't find a combination that works.

How can I perform interpolation twice, or delay interpolation so `${string}` is resolved when the function is called (instead of when the function is created)?

Comment: Why are you using promises here? What is the point of `createPFunc`? Why not just write ``const f1 = string => `String 1: ${string}`;``?

Comment: "*How can I perform interpolation twice*" - you cannot. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607806/defer-execution-for-es6-template-literals

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused/54124803#54124803

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [at this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused/54124803#54124803) to find details on how to defer the substitution of a string interpolation.
I am using the `defer` function here for that.

You can achieve what you want by doing this:

```js
    function defer([first, ...rest]) {
        return (...values) => rest.reduce((acc, str, i) => acc + values[i] + str, first);
    }
    
    var createPFunc = (template) => {
        return (string) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(template(string));
                    resolve();
                }, 2000);
            })
        }
    }
    
    var f1 = createPFunc(defer`String 1: ${'string'}`);
    var f2 = createPFunc(defer`String 2: ${'string'}`);
    
    f1(`search 1`).then(() => f2('search 2'))
    // result:
    // String 1: search 1
    // String 2: search 2
```

Comment: Using `'string'` as an interpolated value is confusing, since it's just ignored - the value has no significance. Better avoid that `defer` tag and just write ``createPFunc(string => `String 1: ${string}`)``.

Comment: That is right, the argument is ignored in this case. It could easily be `null` or `undefined` (but needs to pass something, because of the syntax of es6 templates). I used the word string to make it more alike OP's original code, but yeah, that might confuse someone.