# How do i pass a string which contains a variable to be added to it in function

Tags: javascript

Good day!!! Am trying to pass a string to a function. The string contains a variable which is defined in the function.  That is, it is in the function that the value of the variable will be added to the string that is passed in function call. Something like this as an example

```
function myfunc(arg){
    
    name = "John Malikberry"
    
    alert(arg)
}


let str =`My name is ${name}`

myfunc(str)
```

I would like the output to be **My name is John Malikberry**

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can't. The variable is replaced when the template literal is evaluated, not when you use the variable.

Comment: You can't access variable defined inside function

Comment: You can find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124803/2938526) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129531/2938526)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a template literal, use an ordinary string, and do the replacement in your function.

```js
function myfunc(arg) {
  name = "John Malikberry"
  console.log(arg.replace(/\$\{name\}/g, name))
}

let str = 'My name is ${name}'
myfunc(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this maybe:

```
function myfunc(arg){
    
    name = "John Malikberry"
    
    alert(`${arg}${name}`)
}


let str ='My name is'

myfunc(str)
```

This could work. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, this is also good for what I need

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

> it is in the function that the value of the variable will be added to the string

So it's not just a string. It should take the string and do something with that string *(add the name)*. That's code. The best thing for passing a piece of code around is a function:

```js
function myfunc(template) {
  let str = template({ name: "John Malikberry" });
  alert(str);
}


let template = ({ name }) => `My name is ${name}`;

myfunc(template)
```

Comment: Love this. Thanks!

Comment: Added to my knowledge